# jQuery .next and pseudo selector

Tags: jquery

**Short Question:** Is there a equivalent of `$this.nextAll().filter(':visible').eq(0)` in `.next` or `.nextUntil` jQuery functions?

**Scenario:** I have 3 li, in which 2nd li is hidden. Now How can I select 3rd `li` when `this` is `#test`

```
<ul>
    <li id="test">Item 1</li> <!-- From this li -->
    <li style="display: none">Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li> <!-- Select this li using :visible -->
</ul>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LgCuk/1/

**Note:** Above is just an example, the actual list is huge and the elements are hidden randomly. So I am looking for something that would pick next visible `li`.

Comment: You mean like `$this.nextUntil(':visible').next().css('color', 'red');
`?

Comment: @j08691 That seems to be the only correct answer as per comment on Musa's question.

Comment: Let me know if I should post it as an answer.

Comment: @j08691 ahh I see. Yes, that seems to do what I would achieve using an iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.next()` and `.nextUntil()` will allow you to not have to iterate over the entire list and will stop when the first match is found (`.nextUntil()`) and then select the element you want (`.next()`). It's less expensive than a straight `.nextAll()`.

```
var $this = $('#test');
$this.nextUntil(':visible').next().css('color', 'red');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LgCuk/4/)**

Comment: This is perfect, It would be same if I had to iterate and break. Thanks!

Comment: @Musa = Vega said, "I am looking for something that would pick next visible li". Your fiddle seems to show just that, no?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$this.nextAll(':visible:first')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/LgCuk/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to break after first `:visible` instead of selecting all, filtering `:visible` and then getting :first.

Comment: @Vega I'm not sure what you're asking, unless using `.nextAll` is not an option.

Comment: `.nextAll` - returns all elements, then `:visible` applies the filter, and then `:first` picks the first element. It is a sequence which does extra stuff which could be avoided easily.

Answer (score 0):

sorry you were right. I was incorrect with my original post. This should work as you want though.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').each(function(index){
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
    alert(index + $(this).text());
    }
});
```

});

Comment: That is not how you iterate over elements inside a jQuery object. And not what OP asked for either.